# One fragment To Another fragment using OnBackPressed method in activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, modal-dialog, android-alertdialog, android-fragmentactivity

My Problem Is simple when I press back button that it will be going previous fragment how can i do that and when I click my yes button in dialogue it will be finish show if I click no button that go pervious fragment..

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setMessage("Do you want to Exit?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //if user pressed "yes", then he is allowed to exit from application
                finish();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //if user select "No", just cancel this dialog and continue with app
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert=builder.create();
        alert.show();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First If you commit any fragment Add addToBackStack()

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,new NewFragment()).commit();
```

then

```
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
          if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
              getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
          } else {
              AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
              builder.setCancelable(false);
              builder.setMessage("Do you want to Exit?");
              builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                      //if user pressed "yes", then he is allowed to exit from application
                      finish();
                  }
              });
              builder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                      //if user select "No", just cancel this dialog and continue with app
                      dialog.cancel();
                  }
              });

              AlertDialog alert=builder.create();
              alert.show();
          }
        }
```